# How to connect NOX simulator with Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

I have NOX simulator(like Genymotion) and I want to connect with Android Studio to develop applications. I try a lot of methods but without result.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nox player isn't showing in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51333731/nox-player-isnt-showing-in-android-studio)

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. Open NOX player. Laterst version could be download from the following link: https://www.bignox.com/
2. On the NOX simulator, Go to the tools--> Settings -->Developer options
3. Check the "[USB debugging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4Xzc.jpg)" box.
4. Restart NOX.
5. First open Android Studio and then open NOX.
6. The nox simulator will be displayed in the connected devices.