# Nox player isn't showing in android studio

Tags: android-studio

I have an AMD A10 processor that doesn't support VT-x. I installed Nox player and enabled USB debugging but still Android studio cannot find the emulator. Any helpful and clear steps to install USB driver adb(Android Debug Bridge)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## [Connect a NOX device to Android Studio: By Abhijeet Pal](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p-641mpPUoU)

> On CMD:
>
> > - Route: cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Nox\bin
> > - Connection: nox_adb.exe connect 127.0.0.1:62001

## [Not Connecting Fix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44763328/9621212)

You need to find the correct port and use it. I faced the same problem so here is what I did.

1. Kill the server:

> > nox_adb.exe kill-server

2. Now try to connect on any port number, say, 62001:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Nox\bin>nox_adb.exe connect 127.0.0.1:62001
>
> > - daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037
> > - daemon started successfully
> > - unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:62001:62001

3. Now try to use port 5037 as mentioned in the output above:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Nox\bin>nox_adb.exe kill-server
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Nox\bin>nox_adb.exe connect 127.0.0.1:5037
>
> > - daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037
> > - daemon started successfully
> > - connected to 127.0.0.1:5037

It should work fine then.

## [127.0.0.1:5037 Disconnected on Android Studio Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50216682/9621212)

> It should appear without any further customizations.
>  I have used Nox Emulator for a while and you have to do a little trick to make it work for debugging:
>
> > 1. Click the debug or run button on Android Studio
> >    2. Wait for the popup to open (the one where it lists the connected devices)
> >    3. Run Nox Emulator
> >    4. After Nox is ready and running, it should appear on your connected devices list.
> >        
> >    This isn't of my authorship, that's why I attached all sources of problems that I've faced.

Comment: Worked perfectly, from windows and also with its embeded ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

I made the mistake of starting the adb server before and then opening android studio. It didn't work.

Subsequently did this:

```
D:\Program Files\Nox\bin>nox_adb.exe connect 127.0.0.1:62001
adb server version (41) doesn't match this client (36); killing...
* daemon started successfully *
connected to 127.0.0.1:62001
```

Android studio immediately updated and showed the following:

[image]